# "References" section missing from table of content in epub generated with pandoc

Tags: epub, pandoc

I generate my epub using the standard template.
The epub contains the table of content will all the section except for the "References" section that contains the bibliography.

Is there a way to force the ToC to include it?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [README](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-citations), you can simply put in a header called `References` at the end of your document:

```
last paragraph...

# References
```

Comment: That's what I am doing. The section appears, the bib entries get added. But the section does not appear in the table of contents.

Comment: you mean there is no _References_ in your toc? what exact command are you using?

Comment: pandoc -s -f markdown -o opendata-calculus.epub \
> --template=default.epub --epub-stylesheet=epub.css \
> --epub-cover-image=images/cover2_.png \
> --csl=acm-sig-proceedings.csl --bibliography references.bib opendata-calculus.md